# Not satisfied with original formulation of my question and the answers I received — what steps can I take?

Tags: support, asking-questions, etiquette

I have a question about my Music Fans Stack Exchange post: [Different Artist - same song titles?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/10546/different-artists-same-song-titles?)

I am not happy with the answers posted in my original question and I really needed some answers about "Selena Gomez" and "Katy Perry".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stack Exchange sites may work a different way then other sites you may visit. From our tour:

> Music Fans Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for music
>   historians, critics, and fans. It's built and run by you as part of
>   the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working
>   together to build a library of detailed answers to every question
>   about music history or appreciation.

In doing this, we have a concept of a duplicate questions. This allows users who have experience on the site to recognize the question asked is the same as another question we have already been asked. This helps keep our answers consistent across commonly asked questions and answers. Users on this site have found your questions all really are the same and have been closed as a duplicates due to this.

We also do not allow completely changing your question thus invalidating current answers so your question has now been locked to prevent this.

For this specific question, I think there may be a deeper misunderstanding you have on how song titles are created. While there may not be one way to define this, there's a general pattern that a lot of artists follow that leads to the answers you got are based off of.

My suggestions are the follows:

- Ask a question about how artist determine song title in general.
- Edit your question to be more general about song title overlap between artis
- Ask specific questions about the meanings of the individual songs and how they were made. If they influenced each other (which I doubt) it will show up in those other question
- Post a bounty on your original question when you have enough rep

Comment: But, what do I do so that I can get answers about "Selena Gomez" and "Katy Perry"?

Comment: @ArunabhBhattacharya you have your answer. The titles are generic. Please reread this answer for where you should go from here.

Comment: But, currently I have answers saying that "Daylight" and "This Love" are generic titles. I am not happy with that answer. I need an answer that says "Rise" and "Birthday" are generic titles.

Comment: @ArunabhBhattacharya they are also generic titles hence why it was closed as a duplicate. Last warning please review the suggestions here. Reposting this meta question and the other question is not helping.

Comment: And the other thing is that currently, I only have a reputation of 3. [Here](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) are the privileges get with a higher reputation. I need to reach a higher reputation.

Comment: @ArunabhBhattacharya the only one that requires more rep is the bounty but I specify "Post a bounty on your original question when you have enough rep". 2 of the 4 suggestions will get you more rep by asking more questions.

Comment: So, how can I edit my question to be more general about song title overlap between artists?

Comment: @ArunabhBhattacharya Focus on the pattern across several different artist you already have two and shift the question to the generic concept rather than the specific artists.

Comment: So, how do I shift the question to the generic concept?

Comment: @ArunabhBhattacharya You've noticed a pattern. Use that to shape the question instead of asking the same question with two different artists.

Comment: What is the pattern?

Comment: "Same Song titles"

Comment: So, where do I edit my question and put the generic concept of "Same Song Titles"?

Comment: @ArunabhBhattacharya take a step back. You've produced two questions that are considered duplicates of each other due to them having the same answer. Focus on the why this was and use it to shape your question. You original question is currently locked. I will unlock it so you can do this, but if you continue the path of just asking a very different question I will roll back and lock again.

Comment: The title of my question is now [Different artists - same song titles?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/10546/different-artists-same-song-titles).

Comment: My question is still down-voted to -1. I'm waiting for an improvement in the votes.

Comment: @ArunabhBhattacharya you get votes for high quality content. If you are getting down votes, it's typically because it's viewed as low quality you can improve the quality by editing the question. Right now, your question is a very thin question and mostly two examples. Adding detail on the core question could help improve it, but it's not a guarantee to get votes. If you are posting just to get votes, then you need to take a step back. Trying to force votes will never get you any. Naturally posting questions and answers will give you more.

Comment: What detail could I add on the core question?