# Meta question deleted only 4 months after I last edit it

Tags: support

Courtesy link: https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/705/revisions

I asked [this meta question](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/705/question-about-a-coincidence-marked-as-off-topic) on August 31 2020. I also received two answers to that meta question, and I also accepted [Bebs'](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3260/bebs) answer. I made the last edit earlier this year on February 28. After that, I did not touch this question at all. But 4 months later, [Johnny Bones](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/users/53/johnny-bones) deletes the question, and also removes the accept of the answer I accepted. I cannot understand the reason behind deleting the meta question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your post was flagged for edit abuse for editing just to bump the question. The flag has been pending since that edit for a while and was resolved by deleting the question. In my opinion, a lock would have been better, but the result is the same: while the question is yours, using features like edits the way they are not intended is abuse. Other facts like unaccpeting the answer are irrelevant. Abuse of site features is not tolerated.

Comment: According to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4397/purposeful-question-bumping-abuse-or-feature/4409#4409, editing a question once in a while is fine, but editing a string of questions and flooding the front page is not really useful for anyone. That day, I had edited only that meta question.

Comment: @ArunabhBhattacharya the edit was pure whitespace. From the second sentence of that link "Just make sure your edit improves the question in some measurable way.". Are you saying the whitespace improves the question? It's also not unanswered. Any positive answer means the question is answered. Removing your acceptance does not make it unanswered.

Comment: And now I have flagged my question to appeal the deletion.

Comment: @ArunabhBhattacharya reread this answer. I declined the flag because there's really not a reason to undelete. You seem to want something from that meta differently than what the site decided which neither your whitespace edit nor undeletion will address. The deletion was explained and you haven't really addressed the abuse of site features which is the blankspace edit. If you don't address that, there's no way the a flag appeal will be enough and if you keep ignoring it, there's no more discussions on this.

Comment: Related:https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347505/can-i-get-suspended-for-bumping-my-post

Comment: In my other question here: https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/676/what-steps-can-i-take-if-se-is-no-longer-accepting-answers-from-my-account, I only added a down-vote tag. What was wrong with that edit? It is OK to add or remove tags.

Comment: @ArunabhBhattacharya I'm not having this discussion anymore. The question is clearly not about downvotes and you're clearly just bumping your meta posts for some reason. This fury of flags is also not constructive and is borderline abusive since you keep doing the same thing that we keep pointing out you shouldn't do. This is your final warning. Listen to the feedback here and use site features for their purpose. Not to highlight/bump your own content, not to work around the systems in place, ect.

Comment: OK, I will carefully use the site features and not do anymore useless bumping in my content. I am not going to bump this question.l. Nor will I bump [my other question](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/670/not-satisfied-with-original-formulation-of-my-question-and-the-answers-i-receive).

Comment: I have now gone to [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381443/what-steps-can-i-take-to-appeal-a-moderation-decision-on-a-question).

Comment: @ArunabhBhattacharya I'm not sure what you are expecting there. You're not following the advice highlighted in this answer and you are showing similar behavior where you do not like the question being closed as a duplicate so you are editing to try and work around it. Please just listen to the feedback offered here and there.